# ComparisonCountingSort pseudocode difficulty

Tags: java, algorithm

This algorithm given to us in class:

[image]

I am having trouble in my attempts to determine the output when the input is an array `A[60,35,81,98,14,47]`.

I wanted to get used to the pseudocode syntax, so I tried to convert this to Java syntax, but the resulting program won't show a result.  This is my converted code:

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] test = {60, 35, 81, 98, 14, 47}; 
        int[] converse = new int[6];

        converse = countSort(test);

        for(int i : converse)
        {
            System.out.println(converse[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int[] countSort(int[] a)
    {
        int[] s = new int[6];
        int[] count = new int[6];
        int n = a.length + 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < (n-1);)
        {
            count[i] = 0;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < (n-2);)
        {
            for(int j = (i+1); i < (n-1);)
            {
                if(a[i] < a[j])
                {
                    count[j] = count[j]+1;//What
                }
                else
                {
                    count[i] = count[i]+1;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (n-1);)
        {
            s[count[i]] = a[i];
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`int[] test = {60,35,81,98,14,47};` is never used.

Did you mean to pass `test` into `countSort`? and also do something with it's result.

While I haven't looked at the algorithm really, there is something else wrong here:

`int n = a.length + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1);) {
            count[i] = 0;
        }`

This will loop indefinatetly. `i` never incerements.

Comment: oops left that off, i had it before but i must of deleted it. same issue though.

Comment: The same failure to increment the loop-control variable appears in all four loops, in fact.  This is a failure to correctly translate pseudocode into Java.

Comment: The loop in `j` should be  `for(int j = (i+1); j < (n-1);j++)`. Not only the increment but the terminal condition is wrong. The loop will never stop.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your array `test` is never used.
2. In your for loops, `i` never gets incremented. It will loop infinetely.
3. Instead of `n = a.length+1;` just use `n = a.length`. it makes your code easier to read. You then also have to check all your loops.

When you are running the code with a testset larger or less than 6 integer values your code wont run correctly or even fail with an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception, as you allocate the arrays `s` and `count` for only 6 values.
Try `int[] count = new int[a.length];` instead of `int[] count = new int[a.length];`. The same for `s`.